# EF core migration script error when using with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ef-core-2.2

I have below migration script. I don't know why it's error if I run only **CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION** block it work..

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory" WHERE "MigrationId" = '20190305152943_SupportLocationAndAsset') THEN

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_hierarchey(location_id int default null::int, prefer_depth int default null::int) 
    RETURNS SETOF jsonb AS 
    $$
    BEGIN
        IF prefer_depth < 0 THEN
            RETURN;
        ELSE 
            prefer_depth := prefer_depth - 1;
            RETURN QUERY 
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN COUNT(x) > 0 
                    THEN (((to_jsonb(t) || jsonb_build_object('Children', jsonb_agg(f.x))) - 'SearchVector') - 'ParentLocationId')
                    ELSE ((to_jsonb(t) - 'SearchVector') - 'ParentLocationId')
                END
            FROM "Locations" t
            LEFT JOIN build_hierarchey(t."Id", prefer_depth) AS f(x) ON true
            WHERE t."ParentLocationId" = location_id OR (location_id IS null AND t."ParentLocationId" IS null)
            GROUP BY t."Id", t."Name";  
        END IF; 
        RETURN;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

    END IF;
END $$;
```

Error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"

LINE 8:  BEGIN

         ^

SQL state: 42601

Character: 286
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the delimiter is repeating inside the IF condition

```
DO $$
IF NOT EXISTS .....
$func$
     BEGIN
     SQL/FUNCTION/TRIGGER
END;$func$
END $$;
```